# Is there single word for "time spent for awaiting reply"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I want to articulate that lot of time is getting wasted while waiting for a reply from *this* person. So, is there any one word I can use for "time spent for awaiting reply"

Comment: I'm not sure there is one word to encapsulate this entire idea in one word but there are many variations on how to tell someone you are waiting impatiently or that time is being wasted: **I'm just sitting here waiting around...**, **twiddling my thumbs waiting for your reply**, etc. Is there something specific you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually, I want to convey to other person is that a lot of time is getting wasted waiting for your reply in WhatsApp.

Comment: And you don't mind if you are not simply implying it? In other words, you don't mind being very up front and "vocal" about how much time is being wasted?

Comment: No, I don't mind saying it up front

Comment: I will provide an answer. I'm writing one up now. Give me a moment.

Comment: Sorry I had to reboot my computer. I have updated this with an answer. I hope it helps. Let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer(s) I could offer given the new comment information, since there is not one word to encapsulate the entire meaning asked about, would be some of the following suggestions.

**Include in your conversations at the end of the message, something like:**

*1. Please reply with haste, we are spending too much time waiting on replies.*

*2. I need a quick response please, these long pauses are causing a huge waste of downtime.*

*3. Please, there is no time to dally, we are wasting time.*

*4. Time is precious, please don't dally in your reply.*

*5. We are continually seeing sluggish responses, let's please remember to hastily reply.*

---

I hope these suggestions will help you. There are many ways to say what you want but basically it boils down to finding some pleasant, however forceful, ways to get your message across that *time is of the essence* (you could even include that phrase at the end of the message, for example; or at the beginning to emphasize it even more - maybe preface the whole thing that way).

I would also suggest that you lookup something like [**time wasting synonyms**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/time-wasting) *(SOURCE: www.thesaurus.com)* to come up with some possibly new ideas for words. But the general idea of what you will want to do to get the point across is what I described above using some flavor of that type.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to describe the act of waiting for a reply, I would simply use "**awaiting** [your reply]". I would assume that it is already clear from further context that you are awaiting (the reply from) the person who you are speaking to.

As far as I'm aware, there is no single word to encapsulate the idea of "awaiting a reply for longer than is deemed necessary". Especially if you expect "reply" to be implicitly clear.

Answer (score 0):

.....................PATIENCE :D

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Please don't make this platform inaccessible to the laconic.

Comment: ........SURE :D